# reference in c++ confusion

Tags: c++, reference

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i=9,k=8;

    int &q=i;

    q=k;

    cout<<i<<"\n"<<q<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
8
8
```

But in my book it is given "q=k changes only the value of i and not q. This is because q being a reference gets de-referenced automatically as(*q). Hence the value at the address stored in q is replaced by value of i"
But as you can see value of q also gets changed. Isn't it wrong???

Comment: References cannot be reseated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`q`, as a reference, does not change. In other words, it refers to `i`, **always**, forever and ever (until it goes out of scope). You *cannot* make `q` refer to a different object. That is what is meant by "it's value [sic?] never changes." The "value" of `q` is `i`'s address. When you assign to `q` there, you're really assigning to `i`.

What you printed out there was the value of `i`, and then the value of the object that `q` refers to (which is `i`).

Answer (score 0):

As `q` is reference to `i`, that means it is just an alias to `i` (other name to `i`).

So whatever value `i` will have same `q` will have!

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize a reference as follow

```
int i = 9;

int &q =i;
```

q just becom another alias (you can say nickname) of i, so if any change occurs in q it will reflect in i as well and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize a variable like:

int &q = i;

every time you change i you change q and viceversa.

The reference of q have the same value of i, so them point to the same memory location.